# Get all users under all projects from Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get all users under couple of project. The case is that under users there are many and I need to to use **continuationToken**. The result is messy because my logic is bad. I cannot figure out how to use the second foreach..

```
$outputItems = @()

foreach ($project in $projects) {
    $uriProjectDescriptor = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$OrganizationName/_apis/graph/descriptors/$($project.id)?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
    $projectDescriptor = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriProjectDescriptor -Method Get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
    $descriptors = $projectDescriptor.value

    foreach ($descriptor in $descriptors) {
    do
    {
        $uriUsers="https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$OrganizationName/_apis/graph/users?continuationToken=$continuationToken&scopeDescriptor=$($descriptor)&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
        $responseUsers=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uriUser -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -UseBasicParsing -MaximumRedirection 0
        $continuationToken = $responseUsers.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'
        $userSet = $responseUsers.content | ConvertFrom-Json
        $users += $userSet.value.Count
        $arealList = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            CountUsers = $users.Count
         } | Select-Object "CountUsers"
         $outputItems += $arealList
         $arealList = $null
    }
    while (($continuationToken))
    $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'
    }  
} $outputItems
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following Powershell Script:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organizationname}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"


$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$responses = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json


ForEach ($response in $responses.value.id)
{
   

   $url1="https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{Organizationname}/_apis/graph/descriptors/$($response)?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

   $Descriptor = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

   ForEach ($Descriptor1 in $Descriptor.value)
   {

     do
    {
      $url2="https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{Organizationname}/_apis/graph/users?scopeDescriptor=$($Descriptor1)&api-version=6.0-preview.1"

      $UserLists = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
      $continuationToken = $UserLists.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'
   
    }
    while ($continuationToken -ne $null)
  
    Write-Host "result = $($UserLists | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
   }

}
```

**Explaination:**

The [first Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is used to get the Project name.

Then the [second Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/descriptors/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is used to get the descriptors.

The [third Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is used to get the userlist.

I use foreach nesting to realize the loop of response to Rest API.

**Update:**

Test with the continuationToken and the maximum value of objects returned by a project is 500.

I found another Rest Api [User Entitlements - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) to get the users.

```
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/Organization Name/_apis/userentitlements?top=10000&select=project&api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

This Rest APi could directly return the users under the organization(Project Scope). The max value is 10000.

Comment: I tried it, but again the maximum users are 500, seem the continuationToken is not working

Comment: @Baequiraheal. Yes. I test it again and the max value is indeed 500. It seems that the continuationToken has limitation. I found another rest api that could return 10000 directly. Please check the update.